# Constant subset of a variable length list for some list[[x]] in R

Tags: r, list, subset

Imagine the following data:

```
listA
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

How to select:

```
listA[[1:2]][1:4]
```

Using `1:2` there is not allowed, so is there any way to select these when it is known that this selection exists (both the `1:2` and `1:4` parts)?

What I would like returned:

```
listA
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4
[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Related to what you've figured out: `listA <- list(1:7, 1:5, 1:6); lapply(listA[1:2], `[`, 1:4)`.

Comment: That `"["` is a very interesting shortcut there.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Not sure which answer to accept, one uses the notation of the question, the other uses a nice shortcut `"["`? What would you do?

Comment: If there is one, and if you'd find it, I'll reward the effort!

Answer (score 3):

What about just using `lapply`,

```
R> l = list(A = 1:6, B=1:4, C = 1:5)
R> lapply(l[1:2], "[", 1:4)
$A
[1] 1 2 3 4

$B
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to use `lapply`.

```
lapply(listA, function(x) x[1:4])
```

If your actual list is longer, you can access the first two elements of listA by `listA[1:2]`. So this should work:

```
lapply(listA[1:2], function(x) x[1:4])
```